# during upgrade (14.04 - 18.04) reboot fails in a loop

Tags: boot, upgrade, updates

I tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04 on an ASUS G73 (14.04 had been running for years). I performed the following actions:

install update-manager-core and software-properties-common if not already installed. **(These were already installed)**

Make sure the Prompt line in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades is set to lts (long-term support) **(This was already thus set.)**

Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade
Sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

I was instructed to reboot at this point, but was not successful. I changed the boot options in BIOS but none of the options helped. I found safe-mode instructions for a windows installation, but my computer has never had anything on it but ubuntu, and those instructions were impossible to follow.

Here is the complete sequence of observed events from power-on:

1. ASUS logo
2. full screen burgundy
   2.5 1/4 screen burgundy (with an inscribed line) and 3/4 screen blackish
3. EXEC A LOOP
4. ```
   "-" appears in upper left corner briefly, then all black screen
   ```
5. ```
   "-" appears 1-3 more times, very briefly, followed by all black
   ```
6. ```
   cursor arrow appears mid-screen for 1/2 sec., then all black
   ```

END LOOP

Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct path to upgrade to 18.04 from 14.04.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, but the sequence of instructions I followed said that 16.04 would first be installed, then 18.04

Comment: @user1695839 what instructions did you use?

Comment: That's not possible to reconstruct, because the machine on which I did everything is down. I simply chose what looked like the best source (closest to Oracle) and dove in.

Comment: I will now try to find the web address of the sources I used, but I believe that answering that question won't have any bearing on my original question. I need advice on rescuing the machine from the boot loop.

Comment: The first source was at https://confluence.niis.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12484635

Comment: @user1695839 the upgrade process as dictated by Ubuntu would have done your upgrade to 16.04 directly, then you would have had to upgrade to 18.04 afterwards.  If you followed any 'random instructions' on the Internet you will have run a high risk of bricking your system.  X-Road and other systems solutions are **not** the proper way to have done an upgrade, so if you followed any other instructions other than https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release and `do-release-upgrade` it probably broke your system.

Comment: If you *did* `sudo do-release-upgrade` then it will have put you on 16.04 first.  If you did `sudo do-release-upgrade` after that then it will have put you on 18.04.  Unfortunately, recovering you from a bootloop can be *very* difficult as you run the risk of the system breaking at any point in the upgrades process - it's probable that something that got upgraded is trying to load a config that is no longer 'valid' for that version, or any of a trillion other issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116693/discussion-between-user1695839-and-thomas-ward).